# Error conversion String-Integer en Java

Tags: java, entrada

tengo un problema en java y agradeceria mucho vuestra ayuda.

Estoy elaborando un proyecto en el que estamos trabajando varios compañeros, ademas usamos funcionalidad que nos viene de fuera. El caso es que tengo que hacer el paso de String a Integer.

Ilustro con el metodo usado para la conversion;

```
private int parseoint(String aux) {
    aux.replaceAll(" ", "");
    int numEntero = Integer.parseInt(aux);
    return numEntero;
}
```

Y este el usado para acotar el String a convertir;

```
if (matChu.find()) {
    this.chunk = matChu.group(1);
    this.chunk_parsed = parseoint(this.chunk);
} //....Aqui el codigo sigue
```

Con el primero convertimos lo que sacamos del segundo. El problema es que este es el resultado obtenido;

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" Exception in thread "Thread-2" > queryjava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
```

Se ha usado el debugger y demas, pero ahora llevo un par de dias sin encontrar el error. Un cordial saludo y gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Puedes mostrar el `String` que estas convirtiendo, o por lo menos el formato.'

Comment: En que linea exactamente es el error? has un system.out.print a chunk antes de hacer tu función parseoint para ver que te está regresando

Comment: El error te lo dice, no considera que pueda convertir `1.0` a un integer porque aunque técnicamente esto equivale a `1`, el `Integer.parseInt` no sabe manejar decimales.

Comment: Como mencionó @sstan, al contener un decimal, deberías usar en vez de `Integer.parseInt(aux);`, este `Double.parseDouble(aux);` o `Float.parseFloat(aux);`.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda, eso lo primero. Llevan ustedes razon, pero para una funcionalidad futura correcta solo puedo trabajar con enteros, por lo que pedire a mis compañeros que revisen sus funcionalidades, no tengo muy claro de donde viene ese decimal.

Comment: Perfecto, como dices, pídele a tus compañeros que revisen sus variables, si la variable en cuestión, debe ser entera y por casualidad ellos la han puesto en **float** o **double**, aunque se ingrese un entero, automáticamente se agregaría el decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que estoy viendo estas intentando llevar un numero flotante o double a entero. Para ello solo debes eliminar la parte decimal.
En este caso el valor viene dado por un String pero te sugiero hacer estos cambios para que obtengas el valor entero del numero en cuestión.

```
public int conversor(String numero){
    numero = numero.replace(".", ";"); //remplazamos el separador por otro temporalmente
    System.out.println("respuesta:"+numero.split(";")[0]+" - "+numero.split(";")[1]);

  return Integer.valueOf(numero.split(";")[0]); //luego regresamos la parte entera del numero
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, esta solucion nos ha evitado tener que revisar mucho codigo. ¡Un abrazo muy grande!

Comment: Me alegro saberlo. Recuerda darle una valoración en puntos a la respuesta, Saludos.